# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 expiry date fixed or expiry after a certain number of days?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 expires after a certain time. Is that a fixed date or is that determined at the time of install ? i.e.  is it a fixed number of days ?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this Stackoverflow post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960954/when-is-the-expiration-date-of-visual-studio-2010-beta

Which refers to this MSDN post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/setupprerelease/thread/b833dbcb-63f6-41af-8887-4b6b3d90010c/

"3. TIME-SENSITIVE SOFTWARE. The software will stop running 240 days after you install it or on April 15, 2010, whichever comes first. You will not receive any other notice. You may not be able to access data used with the software when it stops running."

I used "Help" -> "About" on my machine to see how many days are left.

Comment: it's about beta 1, but a similar text is likely included in beta 2's eula.

Comment: I'm using Beta 2, and the Help -> About suggestion works for me.